# Documenting CLI commands with Sphinx doc

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-sphinx

I need to document many CLI commands using Sphinx doc. I have searched everywhere for an extension that could be used to produce an output similar to how github documents CLI commands:

https://developer.github.com/v3/#parameters

Is there any extension that I missed that could help with that? If not, can anyone point the direction to building one?

I need to be able to document for example like this:

```
.. sourcecode:: cli

  $ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed"
```

and have that output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wide range of [themes](http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html) to change the default look of how the `.. code::` directive handles. For instance:

```
.. code::

   $ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed"
```

Outputs with the default theme:

[image: default_theme]

With the [sphinx_bootstrap_theme](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme):

[image: bootstrap_theme]

However, if you wanted to create a closer feel to the github documents you can extend the default css and use the `.. raw::` directive to call a custom class. I created a _static/cli.css file in my docs directory with the following:

```
.cli {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  font: 12px/1.4em Consolas, 'Liberation Mono', Courier, monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 2em 0;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

Then added the following to the conf.py. There are other ways to extend the CSS, but this is just the one I choose at the time.

```
html_static_path = ['_static']
def setup(app):
   app.add_stylesheet('cli.css')
```

Finally in the rst I called the new class using the `.. raw::` directive.

```
.. raw:: html

   <div class='cli'>
   $ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed" <br>
   $ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed" <br>
   $ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed" <br>
   $ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed" <br>
   </div>
```

[image: custom-css]

Now this could be improved with a custom directive.

Answer (score 2):

As @cole mentioned, "this could be improved with a custom directive" - there actually is one already [sphinx-prompt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-prompt/0.2.2) (or check the [github repo](https://github.com/sbrunner/sphinx-prompt))

You can install via `pip install sphinx-prompt` and just add `'sphinx-prompt',` to your `extensions` tuple in conf.py.

After that, you just use the directive  `.. prompt:: bash` with the command underneath like

```
.. prompt:: bash

    curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed"
```

and it will output as

```
$ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed"
```

with the additional nicety that the $ is not selectable.

---

[More examples here](http://sbrunner.github.io/sphinx-prompt/)

You can see it in action [on this page that I'm working on](http://hanleybrand.github.io/mdid-docs/admin_guide/3_software_installation.html) (scroll down, the prompts are yellowish in background)

Comment: This is nice, but there is no example how to write the output of commands. :(